# I'm testing a multi-sig contract using RIDE but I have got the following error?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I'm trying to test out creating a multi-sig test but I keep on running into the same issue  =>  Error occured Error: State check failed. Reason: negative waves balance: 3MwqXaytrPKxhCBaa4pc36SHjFYtqoMo2gX, old: 0, new: -1000000
I've imported the seed into client, and the waves address I get is 3P9rLYJniWsMKeUzq95bzYp7694ffwWbWEG  which has 0.2 Waves.
Why is the account address provided with ide.wavesplatform.com different from the address I get from importing the seed phrase into client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you used the mainnet client but on [ide.wavesplatform.com](https://ide.wavesplatform.com) uses testnet, or the other way round that would be the most reasonable explanation.
It could also be that in one of both cases you have an extra space somewhere (mostly at the end) in the seed.

Yes the IDE by default is set to testnet, 
you can set the network byte in IDE in settings (top right corner):

- for testnet, Node URL: https://testnodes.wavesnodes.com and T=testnet.
- for main net, Node URL: http://nodes.wavesnodes.com and W=mainnet.